# Mac_1609-4::setTxPower() to Set TXPOWER in Application

Tags: veins

How do I control Transmission Power based on certain parameters?
Do I need to use Mixim? If so, is there any tutorials on it? 
OR
Is the only appropriate place to do it is in the mac1609-4 file in the TXPOWER parameter? If that's the place to do it, then how can I get vehicle position to do it? For example I want the transmission power to be 10 at point X and Y on the road.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An application can set the transmission power for every message sent via the 1609.4 MAC layer by attaching a [PhyControlMessage](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/messages/PhyControlMessage.msg) object (as a control message); [see here for an example](https://github.com/michele-segata/plexe-veins/blob/4cdcef1/src/veins/modules/application/platooning/protocols/HumanInterferingProtocol.cc#L115). Alternatively, you can alter the default transmit power via the [`Mac1609_4::setTxPower`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.h#L144) method; [see here for an example](https://github.com/michele-segata/plexe-veins/blob/4cdcef1/src/veins/modules/application/platooning/protocols/HumanInterferingProtocol.cc#L76).

An application that inherits from `BaseWaveApplLayer` can read the current position via its [`BaseWaveApplLayer::curPosition`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h#L175) attribute.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Sommer, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I am able to get the curPosition in my applicaion because it inherits from BaseWaveApplLayer. However I am unable to set the txpower using the attribute mac1609_4::setTxPower() in my application.

Comment: I've amended the answer with an alternate solution that adjusts the TX power for every message. Maybe you'll find this easier to use.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try and post my feedback soon.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Sommer, the latter suggestion worked perfectly for me.