# Modify the maximum sending power

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using Veins-4a2. In my work, I want to simulate a scenario with different maximum sending power for nodes and rsu.

Is it possible to do it in Veins-4a2 please since the pmax defined in the omnetpp.ini file is for all the network?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the transmission power and speed based on the distance between two vehicles in Veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433392/how-to-control-the-transmission-power-and-speed-based-on-the-distance-between-tw)

Comment: Another possible duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47759161/mac-1609-4settxpower-to-set-txpower-in-application

Comment: @ChristophSommer I think in this case you could even do it over the `omnetpp.ini` itself, rather than through code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I also modify the value of pmax  of ConnectionManager and the value of maxTXPower of the physical layer phy80211p please? I didn't find a method like setTxPower to modify them.